# Setting custom header on Spring RestTemplate GET call

Tags: resttemplate, spring-rest

I am using Spring REST Template to call an external public REST API. As part of the API authentication I need send the user-key in the header. I am not sure how to set the custom header attribute in Spring REST template GET call.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
<Class> object = restTemplate.getForObject("<url>","<class type>");
```

I found this can be done with *HttpHeaders* class by setting set("key","value") but didn't find any concrete example.
Let me know if you have any info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resttemplate getForEntity - Pass headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900699/resttemplate-getforentity-pass-headers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To pass a custom attribute in REST request via request Header, we need to create a new HTTPHeaders object and set the key and value by set method and pass to HttpEntity as shown below.

Next RestTemplate, exchange() method can be which has a method param of HttpEntity.

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.set("custom-header-key","custom-header-value");
 HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("paramters",headers);

 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 ResponseEntity<ResponseObj> responseObj = restTemplate.exchange("<end point url>", HttpMethod.GET,entity,ResponseObj.class);
 ResponseObj resObj = responseObj.getBody();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
HttpHeaders createHeaders(String username, String password){

   return new HttpHeaders() {{

         String auth = username + ":" + password;

         byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64( 

            auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );

         String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );

         set( "Authorization", authHeader );

    }};

}
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Actually I found that we can use restTemplate.exchange method and get the response object from the body and cast to object. I will update in answering my question.